# Im trying to plot 2 lines in one graph that exist in the same column using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

the values exist in one column and I would like to display them both on the same graph rather than an 2 separate ones https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1YB0.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyal5.png

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and improve your question. That means, include your code as text, not an image. Full traceback also helps to solve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```py
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```